# How to prevent power led blink on ASUS Prime A320M-K?

Tags: bios, led, asus

My desktop pc's power led (blue light) blinks when it sleeps, and I find it annoying.

I searched on it's BIOS, and found one led setting. I disabled it, but it isn't related to this.

I think that setting is related to motherboard leds (inside pc case).

Any idea how can I disable it?

Comment: Try putting black tape on the light. That is the easiest, non-invasive solution. Also, unless there is an issue, just turn the computer off.

Comment: You should be able to disconnect the LED from the header on the motherboard

Comment: Black insulating tape for no light at all, white in multiple layers if you just want to reduce the glare but still see if it's on.